# SiteCatalyst custom page view event

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have implemented site catalyst for a single page website which contains a form. the form has two steps.
I have added below custom events.

1. event1 to count number of form views.
2. event2 to count number of people who completed step 1.
3. event3 to count number of people who completed step 2.

Since its a single page site and there are no page reloads between any operation, I was under an impression that in siteCat reports Metrics > Page Views count should be same as event 1 count. 
But on all the days, Page views count is more than  event 1 count. 
Is my understanding wrong or is there any issue in implementation.?

Here the code on page's body

```js
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
s.pageName="<%= currentPage.getTitle() == null ? xssAPI.encodeForHTML(currentPage.getName()) : xssAPI.encodeForHTML(currentPage.getTitle()) %>"
s.server=""
s.channel="Form"
s.pageType=""
s.prop1="Form"
s.prop2=""
s.prop3=""
s.prop4=""
s.prop5=""
/* Conversion Variables */
s.campaign=s.Util.getCampOnce()
s.state=""
s.zip=""
s.events="event1"
s.products=""
s.purchaseID=""
s.eVar1=""
s.eVar2=""
s.eVar3=""
s.eVar4=""
s.eVar5="";
var s_code=s.t();if(s_code)document.write(s_code)
</script>
```

Below is the settings for the success event in the admin console for event1.
Type : counter, 
Polarity : up is good, 
Unique event recording : Always record event, 
Participation : enabled.

Thanks in advance for any help.

I am attaching the screens of pulse for the reference.
[image: event1]
[image: event2]
[image: event3]

Here is the code that trigger event2 and event3

```js
//Step1 complete
if(validator.form() && ($("#applicantPincodeErrorMessage").val()=="") && ($("#firstcoapplicantPincodeErrorMessage").val()=="")){
        s.linkTrackVars="eVar1";
        s.linkTrackEvents="event2";
        s.events="event2";
        var purpouseDD = document.getElementById("Purpose");
        var purpouse = purpouseDD.options[purpouseDD.selectedIndex].text;
        s.eVar1=purpouse;
        s.tl();
        s.linkTrackVars="";
        s.linkTrackEvents="";
        showSecondpanel();
 }


//Step2 complete
s.linkTrackVars="eVar1";
s.linkTrackEvents="event3";
s.events="event3";
s.tl();
s.linkTrackVars="";
s.linkTrackEvents="";
```

Comment: How are you popping `event2` and `event3`?

Comment: Because my guess here is that since it's a single page, later on (on the same page), you are basically doing this: `s.events='event2';s.t();` and then `s.events='event3';s.t();`  which would cause two additional page views for the original `s.pageName` value to be recorded. IOW your page views probably add up to `event1`+`event2`+`event3`.

Comment: Though event 2 and event 3 are recorded in the same page, I am doing s.tl(); after assigning to s.events.

Comment: Okay well then at face value, according to what you are saying, you are doing it right and it should line up.  But obviously something is amiss here.  Not sure what else I can really say/do/point out w/out seeing the site in question, etc..

Comment: Do you have other pages with the same pageName?

Comment: @CrayonViolent , -  Thanks of the response! I have attached the screenshot from pulse. since the site in question is not yet live.

Comment: @MisterPhilip -   I do not have any other page with the same name. Thanks!

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd screenshots are cutoff so I cannot verify 100% but my money is on just what I said: whatever you are doing for those, they are not being sent as `s.tl` calls.  If it were an `s.tl` call, then in DP I should see an entry called **Request Type** with a value of `lnk_o`,`link_e`, or `link_d` (which should be the first value, in your case).  **Browser Width** and **Height** are usually the last things on the list before **Query String End** (which is always the last thing), so, near as I can tell, those last 2 are not `s.tl` calls (neither is the first, but you knew that)

Comment: show the code where you are making the `event2` and `event3` calls

Comment: @CrayonViolent - Interesting.. I have added the code snippets that triggers event2 and event3. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Okay so yeah.. `s.tl()` with no args passed is going to cause it to pop as a page view.  You need to pop `s.tl(true,'o','something')`  that 3rd arg doesn't really matter what value it is.. it will pop your custom link report that you'll never look at. But may as well pop it with something like "step 2" and "step 3" or whatever